# finger print reader and .net cf

Tags: .net, compact-framework, biometrics

I am looking for a finger print sdk that can run on .net compact frame work and can make use of the in built finger scanning hardware of pda's like hp ipaq etc .thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fingerprint sensor on an ipaq has no public API.  If you do find a way to interface to it, it will be purely specific to that hardware alone.